# Reducing cost for searching in a SQL Database using Django query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I am making an app that will search for similar drugs using the logic and models that if a drug is in a particular set of classes then other drugs that are in those and only those classes only then it will return those drugs.
Here is the relevant code and dummy data -

**views.py**

```
class GetSimilarDrugs(APIView):

  def get(self, request, format=None):
    #import pdb
    #pdb.set_trace()
    get_req = request.GET.get('drugid', '')
    simi_list = []
    comp_class = DrugBankDrugEPClass.objects.filter(drug_bank_id = get_req).values_list('epc_id', flat=True).distinct()
    for drg_id in DrugBankDrugEPClass.objects.values_list('drug_bank_id', flat = True).distinct():
      classtocomp = DrugBankDrugEPClass.objects.filter(drug_bank_id = str(drg_id)).values_list('epc_id', flat=True).distinct()

      complist = list(comp_class)
      tolist = list(classtocomp)
      if complist == tolist:                
        simi_list.append(drg_id)
  return Response({'result':simi_list})
```

**models.py**

```
class DrugBankDrugEPClass(models.Model):
  drug_bank = models.ForeignKey(DrugBankDrugs, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  epc = models.ForeignKey(DrugBankEPClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Dummy SQL Data**

```
 id   | drug_bank_id | epc_id |
+------+--------------+--------+
|    1 | DB12789      |      1 |
|    2 | DB12788      |      2 |
|    3 | DB00596      |      3 |
|    4 | DB09161      |      4 |
|    5 | DB01178      |      5 |
|    6 | DB01177      |      6 |
|    7 | DB01177      |      6 |
|    8 | DB01174      |      7 |
|    9 | DB01175      |      8 |
|   10 | DB01172      |      9 |
|   11 | DB01173      |     10 |
|   12 | DB12257      |     11 |
|   13 | DB08167      |     12 |
|   14 | DB01551      |     13 |
|   15 | DB01006      |     14 |
|   16 | DB01007      |     15 |
|   17 | DB01007      |     16 |
|   18 | DB01004      |     17 |
|   19 | DB01004      |     18 |
|   20 | DB01004      |     17 |
|   21 | DB01004      |     18 |
|   22 | DB01004      |     19 |
|   23 | DB00570      |     20 |
|   24 | DB01008      |     21 |
|   25 | DB00572      |     22 |
|   26 | DB00575      |      7 |
|   27 | DB00577      |     23 |
|   28 | DB00577      |     24 |
|   29 | DB00577      |     25 |
|   30 | DB00576      |     26 |
|   31 | DB00751      |     27 |
|   32 | DB00751      |     28 |
|   33 | DB00750      |     29 |
|   34 | DB00753      |     30 |
|   35 | DB00752      |     31 |
|   36 | DB00755      |     32 |
|   37 | DB00755      |     32 |
|   38 | DB00757      |     33 |
|   39 | DB00756      |     34 |
|   40 | DB00759      |     35 |
|   41 | DB00759      |     36 |
|   42 | DB00759      |     36 |
```

I am getting the result but the problem is that it iterating through list everytime and thus taking very much time and for lots of data it is really slow. Is there any other way so it can work faster?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do here. Why are you querying the DrugBankDrugEPClass model so many times?

Comment: I think in first query he taking some epc_id  and finding matching values from whole distinct drug_bank_id in that table. For taking epc_id of distinct drug_bank_id he uses loop.

Comment: like there is a drug_id called "DB00752" and it has epc_id = [1,2,3] so I want to search for other drugs that has epc_id = [1,2,3] only and return those drugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your need I think you can simply do like this :

```
get_req = request.GET.get('drugid', '')
# Fetching all the epc_ids that belongs to requisted drug_bank_ids
comp_class = DrugBankDrugEPClass.objects.filter(drug_bank_id = get_req).values_list('epc_id', flat=True).distinct()
# filters all drug_bank_ids thats matcth with the epc_ids in requisted
classtocomp = DrugBankDrugEPClass.objects.filter(epc_id__in = comp_class).values_list('drug_bank_id', flat=True).distinct()
```

**UPD :**

```
get_req = request.GET.get('drugid', '')

comp_class = DrugBankDrugEPClass.objects.filter(
     drug_bank_id=get_req).values_list('epc_id', flat=True).distinct()

class_to_comp = DrugBankDrugEPClass.objects.filter(
     epc_id__in=comp_class).values_list('drug_bank_id', 'epc_id')

d = {}
for k, v in class_to_comp:
     d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

simi_list = [k for k, v in d.items() if v == list(comp_class)]
print(simi_list)
```

I Think it will be little fast than your code because if i'am looping also 
as like you did it's not hitting database in each loop. Also its looping through filtered data.

Comment: Your query is almost working but as you are using __in so it is returning drugs even if one element in the list matches while I need all the elements of the list to match with other drugs epc_id

Comment: can you please tell me is there any other way?

Comment: So are you expecting like if a particular drug_bank_id have 3 epc_id , you want all other drug_bank_ids having all these 3 epc_id ?

Comment: Vikas exactly bro!

Comment: @l0n3_w01f I have added a piece of new code and just check it by run and tell me whether its meets your requirements or not

Answer (score 0):

You can change the loop from

```
for drg_id in DrugBankDrugEPClass.objects.values_list('drug_bank_id', flat = True).distinct():
  classtocomp = DrugBankDrugEPClass.objects.filter(drug_bank_id = str(drg_id)).values_list('epc_id', flat=True).distinct()
```

to

```
drug_ids = DrugBankDrugEPClass.objects.values_list('drug_bank_id', flat = True).distinct()
comps = DrugBankDrugEPClass.objects.filter(drug_bank_id__in = drug_ids).values_list('epc_id', flat=True).distinct()
```

and then iterate over the `comps` result set.

Other optimizations you should do is add `db_index = True` to the necessary fields you're querying.

If you're using Postgres, you can add field params to [`distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct):

> On PostgreSQL only, you can pass positional arguments (*fields) in order to specify the names of fields to which the DISTINCT should apply. This translates to a SELECT DISTINCT ON SQL query. Here’s the difference. For a normal distinct() call, the database compares each field in each row when determining which rows are distinct. For a distinct() call with specified field names, the database will only compare the specified field names.

in which you can do the following:

```
comps = DrugBankDrugEPClass.objects.values_list('drug_bank_id', flat = True).distinct('drug_bank_id', 'epc_id')
```

Edit to add:

Furthermore, you can use add-ons like [`django-silk`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-silk) or [`django-debug-toolbar`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar) to profile your queries and applications

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that I am using MySQL and i will try the solution.